# How to sort column by numbers in Numbers?

Tags: numbers

I would like to sort a column in ascending or descending order by number of objects in Numbers. However, despite setting the 'data format' as 'number' it doesn't understand the right order.

This is the *ascending* order of the column in Numbers:

```
1 apple
1300 oranges
16000 peanuts
671 mangos
91 potatoes
```

When I want it to be in this order:

```
1 apple
91 potatoes
671 mangos
1300 oranges
16000 peanuts
```

Please, see screenshot:

[image]

Comment: separate the number out, in a helper column, then sort on that column. Use left()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think by adding a word to each number you've forced it to sort **strictly** alphabetically, which does make 1, 1300, 16000 etc 'correct'. Removing the letters should revert to **natural** sorting.

Moving the words to a separate column should fix it. An easy way to split the numbers out for searching is to add a column between B and C and set `=LEFT(B2, SEARCH(" ", B2) - 1)` as a formula there.